# Javascript UWA button style

Tags: javascript, css

I would like put a button on the left using css style and a UWA button.
This would be the code:

```
var btn = new UWA.Controls.Input.Button({value: 'Add new',style: {'position:absolute;right:20px;'}}).inject(widget.body);
```

I am not sure how to write the styles to take them into account.
I have tried:

```
style: {'position:absolute;right:20px;'}   -> syntax error '}'
style:'position:absolute;right:20px;'   -> nothing happens, doesn't appear in styles in console
style: {'position':'absolute';'right':'20px;'} -> nothing happens
```

Proposed syntaxes from answers that didn't work:

```
style: {'position': 'absolute', 'right': '20px'}
```

Here is the full code snippet (couldn't make a fiddle work with the references):

```
<head>   

<!-- Application Metas Start -->
<title>TEST</title>     
<!-- Application Metas End -->

<!-- UWA -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://uwa.netvibes.com/lib/c/UWA/assets/css/standalone.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://uwa.netvibes.com/lib/c/UWA/js/UWA_Standalone_Alone.js"></script>

<!-- Application JS Start -->
<script type="text/javascript">
   /* global widget */
   ( function () {
       require({
            baseUrl: '../'
        }, ['UWA/Core', 'UWA/Element', 'UWA/Class', 'UWA/Controls/Input'], function(Core, Element, Class, Button) {
            'use strict';

            UWA.debug = true;

            var myWidget = {
                onLoad: function() {

                    try {
                        var btn = new UWA.Controls.Input.Button({value: 'Add new',styles: {position:'absolute',right:'20px'}}).inject(widget.body);
                        //btn.setAttributes({color: 'red'});
                        }
                    catch (err){
                        alert(err);
                    }
                }
            };

            if (widget.launched)
                myWidget.onLoad();
            else
                widget.onLoad = myWidget.onLoad;

        }); // -- End of require
    }() ) ;
</script>
<!-- Application JS End -->
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's a UWA button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably in the docs. From my cursory glance at it, it looks you should set it through the attributes since style is an attribute:

```
var btn = new UWA.Controls.Input.Button({
      value: 'Add new',
      attributes: {
           style: 'position:absolute;right:20px;'
      }
}).inject(widget.body);
```

See https://uwa.netvibes.com/docs/Uwa/html/Input.UWA.Controls.Input.html

or possibly:

```
var btn = new UWA.Controls.Input.Button({
      value: 'Add new',
      styles: {
           'position':'absolute',
           'right':'20px'
      }
}).inject(widget.body);
```

See https://uwa.netvibes.com/docs/Uwa/html/Element.html

EDIT - Since the above doesn't seem to work, perhaps creating your own Element instead of using the built in Button. In this example, I just reused the classes from the Button so they look the same:

```
 var btn = new UWA.createElement('button', {
                    text: 'Add new', 
                    styles: {
                       'position':'absolute',
                       'left':'20px'
                    },
                    class: 'dark-grey uwa-button uwa-button-root uwa-input uwa-input-root active'
                    }).inject(widget.body);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nmde8m75/

see docs for createElement: https://uwa.netvibes.com/docs/Uwa/html/Element.html

NOTE: That once you make this button absolute positioned, you will need to make sure that the surrounding panel has a height.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those two work, I either get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` or `SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`.

Comment: Can you make a snippet or fiddle so we can see it? That error usually means there's a typo with a missing/extra quote, curly brace, etc. You should be able to open up the JS console in your browser and set a breakpoint on that line and step through it to see exactly where the issue is.

Comment: the snippet has been added. Couldn't manage a fiddle with the resources links in tags.

Comment: I think you'll need to create your own button to set the styles. I edited my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Any idea why you have to specify the .moduleContent CSS style to make it fit when you didn't need it with the Input.Button?

Comment: If the input button styling had worked, you would have needed there too. Now that the styes are being appliedn the only thing in that panel is absolute positioned, so the browser calculates its height based on it being empty. Simply setting it's min-height forces it to be big enough to show the button.

Comment: So had I used margings instead of absolute I wouldn't have had to use CSS?

Comment: Setting margins is still CSS. Its the absolute positioning that makes the panel collapse, so any other CSS wouldn't cause that problem except for "float" which would have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing correct object? `{'position':'absolute';'right':'20px;'}` is not valid, because properties must be separated `,` and not `;`.

Try `style: {'position': 'absolute', 'right': '20px'}`

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` is the error I get, even if I just do `style: {'color': 'blue'}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var btn = new UWA.createElement('button', {
    // you can also use var btn=new UWA.Element('button', {
    text: 'Add New', //you can add value: 'Add New'
    styles: {
       position:'relative',
       left:'20px'
    },
    class: 'uwa-button uwa-button-root uwa-input'
}).inject(widget.body);
```